# How to use Subject (AsyncSubject, BehaviorSubject...) in RxJava2 like the way RxJava1 did?

Tags: android, rx-java2, behaviorsubject

In Rxjava1 we can subscribe Subject to an Observable like this:

```
val asyncSubject = AsyncSubject<T>.create()
Observable<T>.subscribe(asyncSubject);
asyncSubject.subscribe(...)
```

Can't figure out how to achieve the same thing in Rxjava2 Flowable?

I'm thinking about something like this

```
Flowable<T>
.doOnComplete { t -> asyncSubject.OnComplete() }
.subscribe { t -> asyncSubject.onNext(t) }
```

Is there better/more concise way?

Comment: Your first example should work fine... Is there an error appearing?

Comment: @AlexHart yes it works well in RxJava1 but I can not do it for Flowable in Rxjava2.

Comment: Ah, well for flowables you would use a Processor. Like a BehaviorProcessor

Comment: @AlexHart Awesome. Could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RxJava2 Separated things out into `Flowable` and `Observable`.  Flowables are used when you want back-pressure.

Due to this break-out, we have two different types of `Subject` objects, your regular old `BehaviorSubject`, etc. which work with `Observable`, and a new set of classes called `Processors`, such as `BehaviorProcessor`, etc.

These classes work in mostly the same way as subjects, but are utilizable with `Flowables` instead of `Observables`.

In your case, you would want to use a `Processor` instead of a subject:

```
val proc = AsyncProcessor.create<Int>()
val flowable = Flowable.just(1)
flowable.subscribe(proc)
```